# How do I convince my sister that her boyfriend who helped her a lot is not good as a life partner?

Tags: relationships, marriage

My sister, 27, who is 2 years older than me, found her boyfriend on a dating app. My sister was in depression during those days and it was her boyfriend who provided her with emotional support. Now they both want to marry each other.

Few reasons why he is a bad match:

1. Destroyed her Dream MBA B-school application

   Apparently, this guy sucks in English essay writing skills. This guy contributed a lot to her MBA B school essay applications. Our entire family told her to rewrite her essay, but my sister didn't listen. She couldn't get into her dream college and had to settle for some other college. My sister is blind and thanks to this guy for at least helping her secure admission to some other college.
2. Extremely rude and possessive.
3. Inappropriate behaviour

   When I met this guy along with my sister, he passed a needless sexual joke which made me and my sister both awkward.
4. Lied about his salary. His actual salary is 40% less.
5. Unhappy with my sister's academic career progression for own selfish goals.

My sister is blind and wants to marry him only because when she was under depression for 2 months this guy helped her a lot.

The moment I try to convince her about all this, she deviates from this topic and stops listening.

How do I convince her that this boy is not the best match?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because without knowing your sister personally we're not going to be able to provide more than conjecture about what might or might not convince them of anything.

Comment: [This question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/17075/how-to-talk-to-my-brother-in-law-about-my-concerns-about-his-intent-to-propose-t) may also be relevant, especially the top-voted answer(s).

Comment: Hi Michel! While this is currently off-topic, I think [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/4269/) is very similar to your situation, so perhaps it will be helpful to read. If you'd like to try editing your post to be more on topic, I encourage you to read [this meta post](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2618/what-is-the-difference-between-a-convince-question-and-a-good-question), which has some advice on how to reframe "convince" questions as good IPS questions.